# Create a custom drop down select like the one used on twitter when user logs out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create custom drop-down select like the one used on twitter when user logs out and till now I did not succeed :
This is what I achieved but is not working on IE9 :|

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Hz2JH/

```
<ul id="main">
    <li class="username" tabindex="1" >  
        <a>USER</a>
            <ul class="curent_buser">
                <li class="help"><a href="http://www.wikipedia.org/">Help</a></li>
                <li class="logoff"><a href="http://www.wikipedia.org/">Log Off</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>


ul#main {
    color: 232323;
    width: 120px;
    border:2px solid #ccc;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    height:30px;
    background:#f1f1f1;
}



ul#main:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#main > li{
    background: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/crystalproject/24x24/actions/1downarrow1.png') 100% 0 no-repeat;
    outline:0;
    padding:10px;
}

ul#main li ul {
    display: none;
    width: 116px;
    background: transparent;
    border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    padding: 2px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 7px 0 0 -3px;
}


ul.curent_buser li a {
    color: gray;;
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul.curent_buser{
    background:lime !important;    
    }


    ul#main li ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}


#main li:focus ul, #main li.username:active ul {
    display: block;
}

.help{
    background: url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/16/Help.png") no-repeat 100% center ;
    height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}       

.help:hover{    
background: #f4f4f4;


}

.logoff{
    background: url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/on-off.png") no-repeat  100% center ;
    height: 25px;
}


.logoff:hover{
    background: #f4f4f4 ;
    height: 25px;
}

.help a,.logoff a{
    color:gray;
    font-family: Museo700Regular,sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    font-size: small;
}

​
```

So how can I build a custom select like the one used on twitter?

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#demo

Comment: @Rory McCrossan nice but I prefer a clean select with css and html eventually with a small jQuery but not with a mega librarie :| I already have many js libraries on my project ... :(

Comment: It's working in ie9 when I run it, also in ie8. But not in ie7 though. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @SKeurentjes is expanding on every browser but is not opening the link in my example I have wiki page ...

Comment: So, what exactly doesn't work? What are you trying to accomplish? The only thing I notice is how you only use css (:focus/:active) and no js at all as of now. And I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't work in IE9 because of an invalid doctype, making you fall in quirk mode (hit f12 to open the developpers tools and you should see what mode is used in ie. Change it to ie9 instead of quirk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, doesnt require a click to get the drop down. Just add li elements to put the custom images on each menu item.  Straight CSS and works on all browsers I have tested, if you find a browser that doesnt work let me know please.

```
#addMenu, #addMenu ul {
list-style: none;
}

#addMenu {
float: left;
}

#addMenu > li {
float: left;
}

#addMenu li a {
display: block;
padding: 0 8px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#addMenu ul {
position: absolute;
display: none;
z-index: 999;
}

#addMenu ul li a {
width: 70px;
color: #000;
font-weight: bold;
}

#addMenu li:hover ul.noJS {
display: block;
background: #ccc;
color: #000; 
}

#addMenu ul li:hover a {
background: #ddd;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul id='addMenu'>
    <li>
    <a href='#'>MENU</a>
        <ul class='noJS'>
        <li><a href='URL'>Option1</a></li>
        <li><a href='URL'>Option2</a></li>
        <li><a href='URL'>Option3</a></li>
        <li><a href='URL'>Option4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```